# How can you discover the US State that a user is in using CoreLocation with a buffer zone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, ios7

Basically, I am trying to create an application that needs to detect the US state(s) that the user is currently in. To resolve issues with someone being on the border of a state (or multiple states), I was thinking about creating a buffer zone of X miles for each state (or X degrees since lat/lon is done in degrees).

I'm really not sure of how to even detect the state using lat/lon. Do I need to subscribe to a web service such as google reverse geolocation, or is it built into the iPhone?

Also, I'm not 100% sure if this "buffer zone" is a good idea, but if it isn't... what is the proper way to detect the state without having a user who is really in the state being told they are not just because they live on the border?

Answer (score 0):

The logic with distances to state borders is up to you. But you can easily determine in which state you are based on `latlng` information.

E.g., Google API.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

gives location details that you can easily parse. Look for the entry under address components with the `administrative_area_level_1` marker:

```
{
   "long_name" : "New York",
   "short_name" : "NY",
   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
},
```

If you want to stay native iOS you can check out [`MKReverseGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whitout using a web service you have to get the coordinates of the state borders as polygons.
Then do a point in polygon operation.

If you use GPS as location device it usually is  within 10m of accuracy.
That should be no problem for persons living near the border.
However it does not help if the border goes through the house.
Just ignore that buffer, concentrate to make the rest working.